# How optimize a TSQL query using a while (fetching and adding data in the same table)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, query-optimization

I'm writing a procedure who get all the parts and sub parts of a specific machine. But, it's possible than a sub part have also sub parts and so on. At the top level, the part have a revision number, after that, I take the maximum revision number of the sub part, because i want the latest (each revision have the same sub parts, its just the drawing who change and I don't care about it). So far i got this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PartMtl_3](
[PartNum] [nvarchar](50) ,
[RevisionNum] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
[MtlPartNum] [nvarchar](70)
) ON [PRIMARY]
--Here I can't put a primary key because 
--it should be PartNum and RevisionNum and MtlPartNum together
-- but i know some of the data have a null in the revision
-- and tsql don't support a pk null

Input parameter for the procedure @Machine VARCHAR(30)

DECLARE @Mytable TABLE
(
id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
PartNum VARCHAR(70),
RevisionNum VARCHAR(16),
Processed TINYINT,
ParentId INT
)

DECLARE @ID INT;
DECLARE @PartNum VARCHAR(70)
DECLARE @RevisionNum VARCHAR(16)

INSERT INTO @Mytable(PartNum,RevisionNum,Processed,ParentId)
SELECT PartNum,RevisionNum,0,NULL WHERE Machine=@Machine

--Whith this insert I have my top parts for the machine

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Mytable WHERE Processed=0)>0
BEGIN
     SELECT TOP 1 @ID=id,@PartNum=PartNum,@RevisionNum=RevisionNum Where Processed=0
     INSERT INTO @MyTable(PartNum,RevisionNum,Processed,ParentId)
     SELECT MtlPartNum,(SELECT MAX(RevisionNum) FROM PartMtl_3  
      WHERE PartNum=MtlPartNum) AS RevisionNum,0,@Id FROM PartMtl_3 
        WHERE PartNum=@PartNum AND RevisionNum=@RevisionNum
     UPDATE @Matable SET Processed=1 Where id=@Id
END
--other code here to basically insert the result of @Mytable in a real table
```

I know this procedure work, but it's really slow and eat all the resources of the server. So  is it possible to optimize it by using a cursor (I think its quite close to so it so I doubt about that approach) or a set base operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what I would do, is create a table variable to hold all the unprocessed parts you retrieved for each pass.

This would allow you to loop less often and update multiples entry at the same time.

Also, I would create a CTE to compute the MaxRevisionNum in advance, this would remove the need to rerun the query for each record (that is basically what happens when you put a query in a field.

Then I would use join to insert what is required and update the processed part in `@MyTable` at the end of the loop.

This is what the code should look like.

It might need some tweaking since it couldn't be tested against your set of data, but it should be really close to what you need.

```
declare @Unprocessed TABLE
(
id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
PartNum VARCHAR(70),
RevisionNum VARCHAR(16)
)

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Mytable WHERE Processed=0)>0
BEGIN
     delete from @Unprocessed
     insert into @Unprocessed
     select id, PartNum, RevisionNum 
           FROM @Mytable Where Processed=0

     ;WITH cte_partNum as
        ( select PartNum, MAX(RevisionNum) as RevisionNum 
           FROM PartMtl_3 group by PartNum )

     INSERT INTO @MyTable(PartNum,RevisionNum,Processed,ParentId)
     SELECT PartMtl_3.MtlPartNum, cte_partNum.RevisionNum ,0, Unprocessed.id 
     FROM PartMtl_3 
       inner join cte_partNum 
            on PartMtl_3.MtlPartNum = cte_partNum.PartNum
       inner join @Unprocessed  as Unprocessed 
            on Unprocessed.PartNum = PartMtl_3.PartNum 
                and Unprocessed.RevisionNum = PartMtl_3.RevisionNum

     UPDATE tbl
     set Processed = 1
     from @Matable tbl
        inner join @Unprocessed as Unprocessed
            on tbl.id = Unprocessed.id
END
```

---

Some correction made based on OP comments.

Comment: Hi Yan,
First of all thanks for the answer. I Don't know if that change something to your answer, but I forgot to make one little precision, in the partMtl_3 the RevisionNum is for the PartNum only, so i cant do a MAX(revisionnum) group by MtlParNum, because i'll have the revision of his parent, which will lead to some problem ( wont find the sub part of that one).

Comment: Made some changes to reflect to include the information you gave me.